# Changing ActionListener to append StringBuilder

Tags: java, append, jbutton, actionlistener, stringbuilder

Within two statements that have drastically shortened my code I need to add a statement that adds the text of a JButton to a StringBuilder. The ActionListener statement exists to disable the JButtons when clicked (a nice aesthetic), but I want to include if possible the ability to append the StringBuilder within the ActionListener as well. The following is the two parts of this code.

```
theModel.randomLetters();

    ActionListener disableButton = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (!(event.getSource() instanceof JButton)) {
                return;
            }
            theModel.currentWord.append((JButton)event.getSource());
            ((JButton)event.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        JButton dice = new JButton(theModel.letters.get(i));
        dice.addActionListener(disableButton);
        boggleGrid.add(dice);
    }
```

The .addActionListener(disableButton) adds the above ActionListener to each button when it is produced by the for loop. However,

```
                theModel.currentWord.append((JButton)event.getSource());
```

is what I thought would properly append the StringBuilder "currentWord" with whatever value the clicked button holds (hence "((JButton)event.getSource())"). There are no errors per say but I have written separate lines of code in my main class to test whether there are any changes to the StringBuilder when any buttons are clicked. There isn't.

Where and what do I need to do to properly add the value of the clicked JButton to currentWord?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `(JButton)event.getSource()` will cause the `StringBuilder` to invoke the objects `toString` method.  This isn't what you want, instead, either use the `JButton`'s `text` property or the `ActionEvent`'s `actionCommand` property, for example...

```
theModel.currentWord.append(((JButton)event.getSource()).getText());
```

or

```
theModel.currentWord.append(event.getActionCommand());
```

instead

Unless you specify the `JButton`'s `actionCommand` yourself, it will use the buttons text as the `actionCommand`

Comment: @SemicolonCapitalD Glad it could help